# How to split multipart node horizontally?

Tags: tikz-pgf, split, multipart-node

I would like to split the tikz shape.multipart node into 9 equal part for drawing PERT node/network. I could split into three rows but not columns. I want to split that into three columns with each compartment in same size.

[image]

```
 \documentclass[border=12pt]{standalone}
 \usepackage{tikz} 
 \usetikzlibrary{positioning,shadows,matrix,shapes.multipart}
 \pgfdeclarelayer{foreground}
 \pgfdeclarelayer{background}
 \pgfsetlayers{background,main,foreground}
 \makeatletter
 \def\tikz@extra@preaction#1{
{%
\pgfsys@beginscope%
  \setbox\tikz@figbox=\box\voidb@x%
  \begingroup\tikzset{#1}\expandafter\endgroup%
  \expandafter\def\expandafter\tikz@preaction@layer
  \expandafter{\tikz@preaction@layer}%
  \ifx\tikz@preaction@layer\pgfutil@empty%
  \path[#1];% do extra path
  \else%
  \begin{pgfonlayer}{\tikz@preaction@layer}%
  \path[#1];%
  \end{pgfonlayer}
  \fi%
  \pgfsyssoftpath@setcurrentpath\tikz@actions@path% restore
  \tikz@restorepathsize%
  \pgfsys@endscope%
  }%
 }
 \let\tikz@preaction@layer=\pgfutil@empty
 \tikzset{preaction layer/.store in=\tikz@preaction@layer}
 \makeatother

 \tikzset{
mp/.style = {
rectangle split,
rectangle split parts=3,
rectangle split part fill={#1}, 
% rectangle split horizontal,
% rectangle split parts=3,
draw, rounded corners, text width=2cm,
align=center, text=white,
preaction layer=background,       
drop shadow}
    }

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[->,shorten >=1pt,auto,node distance=1cm,thick]
\node (n1) [mp={red,blue,green}]
{
\nodepart[align=left]{one}  1  \\
    \nodepart[align=left]{two}  2 \\
\nodepart[align=left]{three}  3 
};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would not try to hack the multipart nodes further. Rather, it seems more natural to use a `matrix`. The styling can be done with a `path picture`.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,shadows.blur}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix[matrix of nodes,column sep=-\pgflinewidth,row sep=-\pgflinewidth,
    inner sep=0pt,draw,very thick,rounded corners,blur shadow,
    path picture={
    \path (path picture bounding box.north west) coordinate(TL) --
     (path picture bounding box.south east)  coordinate(BR) 
     foreach \XX in {0,...,3} {coordinate[pos=\XX/3] (p\XX)};
     \foreach \XX [count=\YY] in {red,blue,green!70!black}
     {\fill[\XX,sharp corners] (TL|-p\the\numexpr\YY-1) rectangle (BR|-p\YY);} 
     \foreach \XX in {1,2}
     {\draw[thick] (TL|-p\XX) -- (BR|-p\XX) (TL-|p\XX) -- (BR-|p\XX); }},
    nodes={text width=2cm,minimum height=1cm,align=center,
     text=white,anchor=center,sharp corners,inner sep=2pt,thin}]
    { 1 & 2 & 3 \\
     1 & 2 & 3 \\
     1 & 2 & 3 \\};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

One can use the matrix node as a whole or the cells of the nodes just like other nodes to attach arrows etc.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,shadows.blur,positioning}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \matrix[matrix of nodes,column sep=-\pgflinewidth,row sep=-\pgflinewidth,
    inner sep=0pt,draw,very thick,rounded corners,blur shadow,
    path picture={
    \path (path picture bounding box.north west) coordinate(TL) --
     (path picture bounding box.south east)  coordinate(BR) 
     foreach \XX in {0,...,3} {coordinate[pos=\XX/3] (p\XX)};
     \foreach \XX [count=\YY] in {red,blue,green!70!black}
     {\fill[\XX,sharp corners] (TL|-p\the\numexpr\YY-1) rectangle (BR|-p\YY);} 
     \foreach \XX in {1,2}
     {\draw[thick] (TL|-p\XX) -- (BR|-p\XX) (TL-|p\XX) -- (BR-|p\XX); }},
    nodes={text width=2cm,minimum height=1cm,align=center,
     text=white,anchor=center,sharp corners,inner sep=2pt,thin}] (mat)
    { 1 & 2 & 3 \\
     1 & 2 & 3 \\
     1 & 2 & 3 \\};
 \node[right=2em of mat,draw,rounded corners,blur shadow,fill=red!20] (txt){Text};
 \node[below right=1ex and 2em of mat,draw,rounded corners,blur
 shadow,fill=blue!20] (txt2)
 {More Text};
 \draw[-stealth] (mat) -- (txt); 
 \draw[-stealth] (mat-1-3) -| (txt); 
 \draw[-stealth] (mat-3-2) |- (txt2); 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you @Schrödinger's cat, it works perfectly fine, but how do we connect this matrix to another matrix, like nodes? Please help me.

Comment: @RameshKannan You can give the matrix a name like any other node, and connect it in the same way. I added an example.

Comment: That's wonderful. Thank you @ Schrödinger's cat for your kindness, support and time.